# Loop through SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which create a list of items from several joint tables as below:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ...)
WHERE item_color = 'blue';
```

and the result is like this:

```
item_color item_code quantity unit_price
blue       547       50       98
blue       478       35       40
```

I would like to loop through the query for other colors. There are only 10 colors.

Comment: Simply remove the WHERE clause?

Comment: "Loop through" is not really a concept of SQL.

Comment: @jarlh I can't because there are several tables joint in the middle with the item_color

Comment: @Saba you can, you'll just have to post the *actual* query and explain what you really want to do. *Looping* is what you can't/should never do in SQL

Comment: @Saba if you know the colors in advance you could write `WHERE item_color in ('blue','red',...)`. If the colors come from a table you could join with that table. If you need to use completely different subqueries for each table, a) looping wouldn't work either and b) you could use a UNION ALL to merge the results of individual queries, as long as they return the same fields

Comment: _"several tables joint in the middle with the item_color "_ - with `'blue'`? Should be `item_color`.

Comment: You have use where clause result wont contain any other colour. So it hard to know what you want please clarify the question

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want `order by`?

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT ...) s
WHERE item_color IN ('blue', . . . )  -- the colors you want
ORDER BY item_color;
```

If you want all colors, remove the `WHERE` clause.